# Amazon Route53 Record set doesn't work as intended

Tags: routing, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an hosted zone which contains a record set list. I encountered a problem after I made some modifications with my running instances which I can't remember exactly.

**My Record Set List**

[image: my record set list];

www1.mydomain.com works perfect but www.mydomain.com record set redirects me to a website that I never seen before.

I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work..

Comment: In what way does it not work? The shown records seem to resolve through DNS just fine here.

Comment: hello, I should've explained better, sorry. www.mydomain.com redirects me to a web-site I never seen before.

Comment: Can you verify using the browser's Devtools that visiting the domain connects you to the correct IP address? Overall, it sounds like it's not a DNS problem at all.

Comment: It connects me to 35.178.158.4:80 instead of my value which is written on the screenshot. Why it doesn't send me to 18.130.60.166 as I stated?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem is related with my web browser. It probably hold the information of my old running instance ip and redirected me to that ip. I probably should clear cookies. I tried it with different browser and didn't encounter same problem. Route 53 works perfectly fine.